# Live Wallpaper Compatibility Issues

Tags: android, live, wallpaper

I have a Live Wallpaper (LWP) currently live on both the Android Market as well as the Amazon AppStore.  Of the many devices I have tested on I was able to successfully view, download and install my Live Wallpaper on both storefronts.  However, 2 devices in particular were unable to find my LWP on the Android Market, but WAS able to view, download and install my LWP from the Amazon Appstore.  The 2 troublesome devices are:

- Boost Mobile ZTE Warp v2.3.4
- HUAWEI-M835 v2.2.1

Here is my manifest.xml -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.a3mn.fu_exoticanimalprints" android:versionCode="5" android:versionName="1.4" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service 
             android:name=".Main" 
             android:enabled="true"
             android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
             <intent-filter android:priority="1">
                     <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService" />

            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                android:resource="@xml/wallpaper" />
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I initially thought it was something with the USES-PERMISSON but both above devices were able to view, download and install this LWP on the Amazon Appstore.  Only on the Android Market does this LWP show up as imcompatible for those devices.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason the Copy Protection (which was set to ON) was acting as a filter to the above mentioned devices.  Once I set it to OFF, I was able to view, download and install my Live Wallpaper with no problem.  Hope this helps others with this problem.